# fgets and readRestOfLine errors

Tags: c, menu, buffer, fgets

I got errors while creating a menu using fgets and readrestofline function. I don't know where is the error coming from.  Am I missing something? After compiling, errors shows at "fgets", "readrestofline" and "stdin".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int printMenu(void)
{
  int option;
  char input[3];


while((option != 3)||(option < 4)||(option > 0))
{
    printf("Welcome\n");
    printf("---------------------\n");
    printf("1.Play \n2.Display Scores\n3.Quit\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");


    fgets(input, 3, stdin);


    if (input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')
    {
        printf("Input was too long.\n");
        readRestOfLine();
    }
    else
    {
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
    }


    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Loading ...\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Loading ...\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Quitting...\n");
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid ! Please choose again.\n");
            break;
    }
  }
}

void readRestOfLine()
{
int c;


/*read until the end of the line or end-of-file*/
while ((c = fgets(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);

/*clear the error and end-of-file flags*/
clearerr(stdin);
}
```

Comment: 1) `input[strlen(input) - 1]` is UB should `input[0] == '\0'` - but I doubt that is at issue.  2) `readRestOfLine()` should be declared/defined before first use.

Comment: Always test **first** for EOF.

Comment: Code should check the retrun of `fgets(input, 3, stdin);` before using `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> errors while creating a menu using fgets...

Regarding your code line:

```
while ((c = fgets(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

`fgets`, prototype is:
`char *fgets (char Line_Buffer[], int Number_of_Chars, FILE *Stream);`

> Reads characters from the specified input stream into a lineBuffer until end-of-file is encountered, a newline character is read, or (number_ofChars - 1) characters are read. The newline character is retained. An ASCII NUL byte is appended to the end of the string. If successful, the function returns a pointer to lineBuffer.

you have only provided 1 of the 3 necessary arguments.

***Example usage***:

```
char buf[80];//line buffer with space for 80 char
int c;

while(fgets(buf, 80, stdin))
{ 
    //do something with buf
}
```

Also, instead of using the line(s): (undefined behavior)

```
if (input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')  //used twice in your code example
```

Consider testing the contents of the string(s) like this:

```
if(strstr(input, "\n"))//change the second argument to search for other values 
{
     //do something
}
```

Note that your first usage of fgets in the posted code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Good catch on `fgets(stdin)`.  Certainly OP's compiler warning are not fully enabled.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have pointed that out.  But then you just have ;).  By the way, likewise on your comment about the undefined behavior.